# Webpacker can't find https://js.stripe.com/v3/.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, stripe-payments

I'm creating a subscribe page in a rails project that will connect to stripe. On running the page, been getting the following error

> Processing by PricingController#index as HTML   Rendering
> pricing/index.html.erb within layouts/subscribe   Rendered
> pricing/index.html.erb within layouts/subscribe (Duration: 2.0ms |
> Allocations: 643) [Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
> [Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do Completed 500
> Internal Server Error in 115ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations:
> 10890)*
>
> Webpacker can't find https://js.stripe.com/v3/.js in
> /mnt/d/---/manifest.json. Possible causes:
>
> 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment    unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the
>    webpack-dev-server.
> 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
> 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
> 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest. Your manifest contains: {
>    "application.js": "/packs/js/application-c229f7c7014cf8c8d494.js",
>    "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-c229f7c7014cf8c8d494.js.map",
>    "entrypoints": {
>    "application": {
>    "js": [
>    "/packs/js/application-c229f7c7014cf8c8d494.js"
>    ],
>    "js.map": [
>    "/packs/js/application-c229f7c7014cf8c8d494.js.map"
>    ]
>    }
>    }
>    }

The subsribe page header is as follows is as follows.

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= Rails.configuration.application_name %></title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= tag :meta, name: "stripe_key", content: Rails.application.credentials.stripe_publishable_key %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the following line

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

with

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```